# makefile custom functions

Tags: cross-platform, makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to make a custom function in a Makefile to detect the current platform and return the proper file accordingly.  Here is my attempt.

```
UNAME := $(shell uname -s)

define platform
    ifeq ($(UNAME),Linux)
        $1
    else ifneq ($(findstring MINGW32_NT, $(UNAME)),)
        $2
    else ifeq ($(UNAME),Darwin)
        $3
    endif
endef

all:
    @echo $(call platform,linux,windows,mac)
```

It fails with the following error.

```
/bin/sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
[Finished]make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be to concatenate outputs of `uname` to form a platform string in a certain format and have platform specific makefiles named accordingly:

```
ARCH := $(firstword $(shell uname -m))
SYS := $(firstword $(shell uname -s))

# ${SYS}.${ARCH} expands to Linux.x86_64, Linux.i686, SunOS.sun4u, etc..
include ${SYS}.${ARCH}.mk
```

Answer (score 3):

`ifeq ... else ... endif` are [conditional directives](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Syntax) in GNU Make, they can't appear inside `define ... endef` because the latter treats them as a literal text. (Try to remove `@` sign near `echo` command and you will see the actual result of evaluating `platform` function)

I'd move conditionals out of the `define` directive. Anyway, the target platform can't change during the execution of Make, so there is no need to parse `$(UNAME)` each time you call `platform`.

```
ifeq ($(UNAME),Linux)
    platform = $1
else ifneq ($(findstring MINGW32_NT, $(UNAME)),)
    platform = $2
else ifeq ($(UNAME),Darwin)
    platform = $3
endif
```