# SVN + Dropbox: sync project on Windows and Mac

Tags: xcode, windows, svn, osx-lion, dropbox

I'm new to SVN so please be patient with my (maybe weird) question.

I have been working on a project with SVN on Windows 7 using Tortoise and WAMP for developing on my local machine.

As all the project is inside my Dropbox folder I'm wondering if there's a way to work on this even on my mac laptop with OSX Lion when I'm away from home (using xCode or whatever) and maintain consistency on both systems.

I read on the web about syncing xcode project with dropbox on several macs, but can it be done between windows and osx?

Answer (score 3):

The idea with SVN is that you have a host where you push your code to. This host runs an svn server which manages your code and is able to distribute the code to multiple clients and accept changes from these clients. So if you have an SVN server somewhere, you don't need to use DropBox at all - just checkout your code from the server on your Mac and you can work on it and push changes to your server. On your Windows system, you can then just update your copy and get the latest changes that you pushed from your Mac.

If, however, you are using a local SVN server which stores your repository in your dropbox folder, things are a bit different. First thing to say: I would never do that. Second thing: You'd have to configure an SVN server on your OSX system to use the repository in your Dropbox folder the same way the server you configured on your Windows system does. If I ever needed to use a setup like that, I would never use SVN for it. A decentralized version control system like git or Mercurial is much better suited to handle this setup, because you don't need to have a server running - you can just sync between the DropBox folder and your local copy.

Comment: Many thanks flyx for your words, I actually need an overview on svn as I'm totally new to this. 
In the specific case I'm talking about, I do not setup the server, I've been added as dev on that project, so they made a new repository for me and they gave me access credentials. 
As I need to build a new module for that project I made a full copy of the website in my local windows machine (with wamp) for build, run and test locally and uploading all my files at the end, in once, when the module would be complete.

Comment: You may want to dive in the [book by Red Bean](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) to get a grasp on working with svn.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use git? If you're new, don't bother learning something that's obsolete.

Be aware that different IDEs (XCode on OSX vs. whatever you're using on Win7) may mangle your line endings everytime you save from that computer.

Git has decent support for this sort of problem:
[What's the best CRLF (carriage return, line feed) handling strategy with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170961/whats-the-best-crlf-handling-strategy-with-git)

Finally, I'm not sure how you expect to "share" the project between two different build systems.

If you have a Makefile for your Windows build, you can make it a cross-platform one. See this:
[makefile custom functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346147/makefile-custom-functions)

Comment: Rahul, actually I have not the ability to choose between svn or git. I've been added in a project already existent based on svn server. But thank you for sharing your opinion.

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize that. All the best with your project!